# terraform how to properly implement delay with time_sleep resource

Tags: foreach, terraform, delay

A resource created by terraform after its creation comsumes CPU/RAM on cluster where it is created,
so some kind of delay is needed before the next resource on the same cluster is created.

As an option to achieve this it was decided to use time_sleep terraform resource to implement
some delay before resources creation.

It was also decided to use -parallelism=1 so that resources were created one by one.

Let's say we have a module (as simple as it could be):

module test, main.tf

```
resource "time_sleep" "wait_3_seconds" {
  create_duration = "3s"
}

resource "null_resource" "topic_events" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = timestamp()
    topic = var.topic_name
  }
  depends_on = [time_sleep.wait_3_seconds]
}
```

module test, variables.tf

```
variable topic_name {}
```

Main module invokes module test (see above):

```
module "test" {
  for_each= tomap(var.environments[var.dim_arr].clusters.events.topics)
  source = "./test"
  topic_name = "${var.dim_arr}.${each.value.topic}"
}
```

The logic is that input values are handled in the loop but because of the time_sleep
resource in the test module some delay is introduced to this loop, that in turn
should decrease a load to the server.

However terraform tries to create all time_sleep resources in the nested module
and then inerates through the objects in the main module and creates them this way:

a) all time_sleep resources are created

b) all resources that depend on them (see a)) are created

Is there any way to change this logic, so that

-resouce that uses time sleep is created

-time_sleep resource causes delay to decrease a load on the cluster

-next object in the loop is handled

Any suggestions or ideas are appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: TF is declarative programing language, not procedural. What you are trying to do, is simply now the way TF was designed to do. Why not use other IoC tools which would allow you to do what you want properly?

Comment: I have a for_each cycle. Inside this cycle are handled resouces, however instead of the loop terraform splits the work onto the 2 parts (disregards depends_on) and creates first part and t hen links it to the second part, instead of creating resources one ny one

time_sleep resource is present to achieve what I would like to implement.

Comment: I was just testing a few things and the `depends_on` is very very strict, there is almost nothing we can do there I tried creating two modules both with `for_each` and having a dependency between them using the index `depends_on = [module.test2[each.key]]` but not allowed, it errors out with  `A single static variable reference is required: only attribute access and indexing with constant keys. No calculations, function calls, template expressions, etc are allowed here`

Answer (score 2):

The only way I found is to use an external source to determine if it is time to run, if not we wait and all other resources in the module will have to depend on this wait or on other resources that depend on the wait...

I have the code here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/tree/master/TerraForm/sequential_wait

The idea is to create a file that will keep count for us of who is running now and everyone else waits, I'm creating the file using a null resource:

```
resource "null_resource" "set_initial_state" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
    command = "echo \"0\" > counter"
  }
}
```

Then inside your module we check that file and wait:

```
resource "null_resource" "wait" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
    command = "while [[ $(cat counter) != \"${var.index}\" ]]; do sleep 5; done; sleep 3;"
  }
}
```

Here is the output of a `terraform apply`

```txt
module.test["3"].null_resource.wait: Creating...
module.test["0"].null_resource.wait: Creating...
module.test["2"].null_resource.wait: Creating...
null_resource.set_initial_state: Creating...
module.test["1"].null_resource.wait: Creating...
module.test["2"].null_resource.wait: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
module.test["0"].null_resource.wait: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
module.test["2"].null_resource.wait (local-exec): Executing: ["bash" "-c" "while [[ $(cat counter) != \"2\" ]]; do sleep 5; done; sleep 3;"]
module.test["3"].null_resource.wait: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
module.test["3"].null_resource.wait (local-exec): Executing: ["bash" "-c" "while [[ $(cat counter) != \"3\" ]]; do sleep 5; done; sleep 3;"]
null_resource.set_initial_state: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
null_resource.set_initial_state (local-exec): Executing: ["bash" "-c" "echo \"0\" > counter"]
module.test["0"].null_resource.wait (local-exec): Executing: ["bash" "-c" "while [[ $(cat counter) != \"0\" ]]; do sleep 5; done; sleep 3;"]
null_resource.set_initial_state: Creation complete after 0s [id=8614789881521489088]
module.test["1"].null_resource.wait: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
module.test["1"].null_resource.wait (local-exec): Executing: ["bash" "-c" "while [[ $(cat counter) != \"1\" ]]; do sleep 5; done; sleep 3;"]
module.test["0"].null_resource.wait: Creation complete after 3s [id=2055094284904046261]
module.test["0"].null_resource.test: Creating...
module.test["0"].null_resource.test: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
module.test["0"].null_resource.test (local-exec): Executing: ["bash" "-c" "date"]
module.test["0"].null_resource.test (local-exec): Tue Nov 30 14:02:16 EST 2021
module.test["0"].null_resource.test: Creation complete after 0s [id=4696397823999126287]
module.test["0"].null_resource.inc: Creating...
module.test["0"].null_resource.inc: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
module.test["0"].null_resource.inc (local-exec): Executing: ["bash" "-c" "echo \"1\" > counter"]
module.test["0"].null_resource.inc: Creation complete after 0s [id=6621987075727255534]
module.test["1"].null_resource.wait: Creation complete after 8s [id=8925579995767074961]
module.test["1"].null_resource.test: Creating...
module.test["1"].null_resource.test: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
module.test["1"].null_resource.test (local-exec): Executing: ["bash" "-c" "date"]
module.test["1"].null_resource.test (local-exec): Tue Nov 30 14:02:21 EST 2021
module.test["1"].null_resource.test: Creation complete after 0s [id=5320532609227697061]
module.test["1"].null_resource.inc: Creating...
module.test["1"].null_resource.inc: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
module.test["1"].null_resource.inc (local-exec): Executing: ["bash" "-c" "echo \"2\" > counter"]
module.test["1"].null_resource.inc: Creation complete after 0s [id=5315818672844469230]
module.test["2"].null_resource.wait: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.test["3"].null_resource.wait: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.test["2"].null_resource.wait: Creation complete after 13s [id=3209055618166905619]
module.test["2"].null_resource.test: Creating...
module.test["2"].null_resource.test: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
module.test["2"].null_resource.test (local-exec): Executing: ["bash" "-c" "date"]
module.test["2"].null_resource.test (local-exec): Tue Nov 30 14:02:26 EST 2021
module.test["2"].null_resource.test: Creation complete after 0s [id=4919718470589558801]
module.test["2"].null_resource.inc: Creating...
module.test["2"].null_resource.inc: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
module.test["2"].null_resource.inc (local-exec): Executing: ["bash" "-c" "echo \"3\" > counter"]
module.test["2"].null_resource.inc: Creation complete after 0s [id=1455157426309278256]
module.test["3"].null_resource.wait: Creation complete after 18s [id=8455991137394172301]
module.test["3"].null_resource.test: Creating...
module.test["3"].null_resource.test: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
module.test["3"].null_resource.test (local-exec): Executing: ["bash" "-c" "date"]
module.test["3"].null_resource.test (local-exec): Tue Nov 30 14:02:31 EST 2021
module.test["3"].null_resource.test: Creation complete after 0s [id=3412367143530453609]
module.test["3"].null_resource.inc: Creating...
module.test["3"].null_resource.inc: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
module.test["3"].null_resource.inc (local-exec): Executing: ["bash" "-c" "echo \"4\" > counter"]
module.test["3"].null_resource.inc: Creation complete after 0s [id=4184091859253605007]

Apply complete! Resources: 13 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```