# Terraform set delay for RBAC reassignments

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am able to create rbac permissions for resources in Azure e.g. rbac on containers within the datalake.
Now , this works.

I however had to refactor the module a bit, which was causing the key to be changed , which was fine.
Terraform recognized it and the terraform plan, showed that it would drop the rbac role and then recreate it.

However the apply failed in the first attempt, because the drop had not completed, when the creation had started.
How do I control this?
This essentially happens, because rbac takes a few seconds to get applied.
I can't use depends on, because it is the same resource (rbac permission).

Rerunning the apply a 2nd time, worked- because by then the destruction was complete.

How do I make terraform wait for destruction to be completed, before recreating ?

this is the pipeline failure

```
# module.external-storage.azurerm_role_assignment.rbac_permissions["datalakename-gips"] will be destroyed
  # (because key ["datalakename-gips"] is not in for_each map)
  - resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "rbac_permissions" {
      - id                   = "/subscriptions/guid/resourceGroups/rg-datalake-cvdev/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/datalakename/blobServices/default/containers/gips/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/guid" -> null
      - name                 = "some guid" -> null
      - principal_id         = "some guid" -> null
      - principal_type       = "ServicePrincipal" -> null
      - role_definition_id   = "/subscriptions/some guid/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/some guid" -> null
      - role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Contributor" -> null
      - scope                = "/subscriptions/some guid/resourceGroups/rg-datalake-cvdev/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/datalakename/blobServices/default/containers/gips" -> null
    }

  # module.external-storage.azurerm_role_assignment.rbac_permissions["datalakename-gips-some guid-Storage Blob Data Contributor"] will be created
  + resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "rbac_permissions" {
      + id                               = (known after apply)
      + name                             = (known after apply)
      + principal_id                     = "some guid"
      + principal_type                   = (known after apply)
      + role_definition_id               = (known after apply)
      + role_definition_name             = "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
      + scope                            = "/subscriptions/some guid/resourceGroups/rg-datalake-cvdev/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/datalakename/blobServices/default/containers/gips"
      + skip_service_principal_aad_check = (known after apply)
    }

 Error: authorization.RoleAssignmentsClient#Create: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=409 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=409 Code="RoleAssignmentExists" Message="The role assignment already exists."
│ 
│   with module.external-storage.azurerm_role_assignment.rbac_permissions["datalakename-gips-some guid-Storage Blob Data Contributor"],
│   on modules/external-storage/additional_container_permissions.tf line 14, in resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "rbac_permissions":
│   14: resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "rbac_permissions" {
```

this is my module (the new one with the change which caused the drop and recreate , which was what was intended)

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "rbac_permissions" {
  for_each             = { for container_accesslist_iter in local.container_additional_accesslist : "${container_accesslist_iter.datalake_account_name}-${container_accesslist_iter.container_name}-${container_accesslist_iter.principal}-${container_accesslist_iter.privilege}" => container_accesslist_iter }
  scope                = local.containers_with_resource_manager_id["${each.value.datalake_account_name}-${each.value.container_name}"]
  role_definition_name = each.value.privilege
  principal_id         = each.value.principal
}
```

this is the terraform resource: [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/role_assignment), and I can't see any property to achieve this wait.

Like I said, rerunning terraform apply after a few seconds works , since by then the destruction was complete.

Comment: Maybe just wait, like [`time_sleep` (Resource)](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs/resources/sleep)? See also [How to properly implement delay with `time_sleep` resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70151358/). It might also be possible to [Create resource dependencies](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/configuration-language/dependencies).

Comment: resource dependency is not option, like I mentioned in the question. This is the same resource. It is simply a drop operation (because I changed the key in the foreach), and a create operation with a new key. I can't create dependency on an object which is getting dropped, as it is not in the module anymore. The other thread seems a little interesting.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to set delay for RBAC reassignments using terraform I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The challenge you're facing with Terraform and Azure RBAC role assignments is a common one in infrastructure as code (IaC) scenarios, particularly due to the asynchronous nature of cloud service provider APIs.

Here the challenge you're facing the issue arises because the Azure API hasn't completed the deletion of the old role assignment before Terraform attempts to create the new one.

To over come this issue I tried a terraform configuration which helps in maintaining the delay to till the delation of old role before assigning new one.

**My terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

# Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorg-vk"
  location = "West Europe"
}

# Data Lake Storage Gen2 Account
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "datalake_account" {
  name                     = "demovkdatala"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  is_hns_enabled           = true # Enables Hierarchical Namespace for Data Lake Storage Gen2
}

# Storage Container within the Data Lake Storage Gen2 Account
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "example_container" {
  name                  = "demovkcontainer"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.datalake_account.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

# Local variables for RBAC role assignment
locals {
  container_additional_accesslist = [
    {
      datalake_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.datalake_account.name
      container_name        = azurerm_storage_container.example_container.name
      principal             = "b70519fb-7ca5-446d-b788-a5268970efd7" 
      privilege             = "Storage Blob Data Contributor"  # Role definition
    }
  ]

  containers_with_resource_manager_id = {
    "${azurerm_storage_account.datalake_account.name}-${azurerm_storage_container.example_container.name}" = "${azurerm_storage_account.datalake_account.id}/blobServices/default/containers/${azurerm_storage_container.example_container.name}"
  }
}

# RBAC Role Assignment
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "rbac_permissions" {
  for_each             = { for container_accesslist_iter in local.container_additional_accesslist : "${container_accesslist_iter.datalake_account_name}-${container_accesslist_iter.container_name}-${container_accesslist_iter.principal}-${container_accesslist_iter.privilege}" => container_accesslist_iter }
  scope                = local.containers_with_resource_manager_id["${each.value.datalake_account_name}-${each.value.container_name}"]
  role_definition_name = each.value.privilege
  principal_id         = each.value.principal

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

# Delay Mechanism
resource "null_resource" "delay" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_role_assignment.rbac_permissions]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sleep 60"
  }
}
```

For complex scenarios requiring custom logic or scripts, a `null_resource` with a `local-exec` provisioner might be more appropriate whereas simple delay with minimal complexity and clear intent, the `time_sleep` resource is preferable.

**Output:**

[image]

[image]